# CANFD in normal mode is not sending message

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, can-bus

I am using the stm32mp157C-DK2 board to communicate via FDCAN and my idea is to use it as normal mode to send and receive CAN messages. For this I have created a program in stm32cubeide and I enable FDCAN1 with the following parameters (source clock: 24MHz and FDCAN1 125Kb/s):

```
 hfdcan1.Instance = FDCAN1;

 hfdcan1.Init.FrameFormat = FDCAN_FRAME_CLASSIC;

 hfdcan1.Init.Mode = FDCAN_MODE_NORMAL;

 hfdcan1.Init.AutoRetransmission = ENABLE;

 hfdcan1.Init.TransmitPause = DISABLE;

 hfdcan1.Init.ProtocolException = DISABLE;

 hfdcan1.Init.NominalPrescaler = 8;

 hfdcan1.Init.NominalSyncJumpWidth = 3;

 hfdcan1.Init.NominalTimeSeg1 = 20;

 hfdcan1.Init.NominalTimeSeg2 = 3;

 hfdcan1.Init.DataPrescaler = 16;

 hfdcan1.Init.DataSyncJumpWidth = 6;

 hfdcan1.Init.DataTimeSeg1 = 5;

 hfdcan1.Init.DataTimeSeg2 = 6;

 hfdcan1.Init.MessageRAMOffset = 0;

 hfdcan1.Init.StdFiltersNbr = 1;

 hfdcan1.Init.ExtFiltersNbr = 0;

 hfdcan1.Init.RxFifo0ElmtsNbr = 1;

 hfdcan1.Init.RxFifo0ElmtSize = FDCAN_DATA_BYTES_8;

 hfdcan1.Init.RxFifo1ElmtsNbr = 0;

 hfdcan1.Init.RxFifo1ElmtSize = FDCAN_DATA_BYTES_8;

 hfdcan1.Init.RxBuffersNbr = 0;

 hfdcan1.Init.RxBufferSize = FDCAN_DATA_BYTES_8;

 hfdcan1.Init.TxEventsNbr = 0;

 hfdcan1.Init.TxBuffersNbr = 0;

 hfdcan1.Init.TxFifoQueueElmtsNbr = 5;

 hfdcan1.Init.TxFifoQueueMode = FDCAN_TX_FIFO_OPERATION;

 hfdcan1.Init.TxElmtSize = FDCAN_DATA_BYTES_8;

 if (HAL_FDCAN_Init(&hfdcan1) != HAL_OK)

 {

  Error_Handler();

 }
```

I have also changed FDCAN1 pins to be able to connect to the board (FDCAN_RX --> PA11 and FDCAN_TX --> PA12). Finally, I have created the program to send message via CAN:

```
 while (1)
 {
 sprintf ((char *)TxData1, "CAN1: %d", indx++);

  if (HAL_FDCAN_AddMessageToTxFifoQ(&hfdcan1, &TxHeader1, TxData1)!= HAL_OK)
 {
 Error_Handler();
 }
 HAL_Delay (1000);
 }
```

I've tried in external loopback mode and everything is ok, but when I run this program in normal mode, I can't send messages and always get the same error:

HAL_FDCAN_ERROR_FIFO_FULL;

It seems that the FDCAN is not sending messages.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks!

Comment: FIFO full rather suggests that nobody is listening. Monitor the CAN tx pin of your MCU with a scope. When developing for CAN, you need to have a CAN bus of at least 2 nodes. See [What are the most common causes of CAN bus communication errors?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276251)

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification @Lundin. Using an ixxat and the minimom software to view messages, can I receive or send CAN messages using a single device (stm32mp157)?

Comment: Only if it is set as active node and not passive listener. CAN listeners are normally passive not to interfere with the bus traffic.

Comment: I just checked IXXAT "canAnalyser Mini" (used to be Minimon) and you can go settings then there's a setting "Tx passive". It needs to be unchecked and then you can use only one other CAN node except the listener.

Comment: thank you very much @Lundin!  I'll try to do the tests as you tell me ;)